# Oracle ADF create new row on pressing Enter key on inputtext

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-adf

I want to create new row to insert data when i press enter key in InputText field. I tried to achieve this by using Javascript to check the if enter key is pressed and set client and server listener to the input field but doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me where have did I go wrong?
My JSFF Page :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
             <af:resource type="javascript">
function handleEnterEvent() {
  var _keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
  if (_keyCode == AdfKeyStroke.ENTER_KEY ){    
      var comp = evt.getSource();
      AdfCustomEvent.queue(comp, "EnterEvent", {fvalue:comp.getSubmittedValue()}, false);
      evt.cancel();

  }
}
</af:resource>
<af:table value="#{bindings.TransMstView1.collectionModel}" var="row" 
rows="#{bindings.TransMstView1.rangeSize}"
        emptyText="#{bindings.TransMstView1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
        rowBandingInterval="0" fetchSize="#{bindings.TransMstView1.rangeSize}" id="t1">
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.label}" id="c1">
  <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.TrNo.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.label}"
                required="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.precision}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.tooltip}" id="it1">
    <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.TrNo.validator}"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrNo.format}"/>
  </af:inputText>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.label}" id="c2">
  <af:inputDate value="#{row.bindings.TrDt.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.label}"
                required="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.displayWidth}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.tooltip}" id="id1">
    <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.TrDt.validator}"/>
    <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrDt.format}"/>
  </af:inputDate>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.label}" id="c3">
  <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.TrMode.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.label}"
                required="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.precision}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.tooltip}" id="it2">
    <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.TrMode.validator}"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrMode.format}"/>
  </af:inputText>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.label}" id="c4">
  <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.TrType.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.label}"
                required="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.precision}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.tooltip}" id="it3">
    <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.TrType.validator}"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.TransMstView1.hints.TrType.format}"/>
    <af:clientListener method="handleEnterEvent" type="keyPress"/>
     <af:serverListener type="EnterEvent" method="#
{backingBeanScope.backing_mas.handleEnterEvent}"/>
</af:inputText>


</af:column>
</af:table>
</ui:composition>
```

My method in backing bean:

```
  public void handleEnterEvent(ClientEvent ce) {

  ViewObject vo = this.getTransMstView1();
  vo.executeEmptyRowSet();
  Row row = vo.createRow();
  vo.insertRow(row);
  vo.setCurrentRow(row);

  }
```

Comment: Your JS function handleEnterEvent should have a parameter (evt)!

Comment: That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution, and that is to use [af:subform](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_subform.html), it has an attribute called defaultCommand which maps to a button, this button will be executed when you press enter on an input text!

Comment: af:subform would work for form only if i am right. But my requirement is that i am dragging the data control and choosing Table view not Form view.